# javascript Object.each is not a function

Tags: javascript, object, jquery-ui

While iterating over an object i get the error,
Object.each is not a function,
Here's my code:

```
$("#print").click(function() {
        $values = {};
        $("[data-type=text]").each(function(i,e){
            if($(e).val() !='') {
                $values[$(e).attr('name')] = $(e).val();
            }
        });
        console.log($values);

        $values.each(function(i,e){
            console.log(i.e);
        });
    });
```

moreover, i can't use for loop too, since i don't know the keys .

Comment: typo error, console.log(i,e);

Comment: `$values` is an object, why not use `Object.values( $values ).forEach( /*...*/ )` or `Object.keys( $values ).forEach( /*...*/ )`

Comment: It is `forEach` !!!

Comment: Using `forEach` Solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$values` is not a jQuery Object and `.each()` will not work.

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

You will want to use `$.each()` instead:

```
$.each($values, function(k,v){
    console.log(k + ": " + v);
});
```

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

You can also just send an Object (jQuery or not) to console:

```
console.log($values);
```